# finding files in directories linked to by soft links

Tags: linux, bash, find, symlink

```
ln -s /horribly/long/and/annoyin/path/to/java/jdk java
```

Now,

```
$ find java -name "jni.h"
$ cd java && find . -name "jni.h" && cd ..
./include/jni.h
```

It seems counter-intuitive that the file is not found when you aren't `cd`-ing to the directory.

Is this expected behaviour or am I just using the commands wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is expected, as [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) says:

> -P 
>   Never follow symbolic links. This is the default behaviour. When find examines or prints information a file, and the file is a symbolic link, the information used shall be taken from the properties of the symbolic link itself.

try:

`find java/ -name "jni.h"`

or

`find -L java/ -name "jni.h"`

as:

> -L     Follow symbolic links. ...